# Is there any way to use Entity Framework with mysql and php?

Tags: php, entity-framework

I want to know that is there any way to use `Entity Framework` with `mysql` and `php`.Is any connector or special program needed.
Could you please introduce me some references to read?

Comment: You mean like this? https://www.google.ch/search?q=entity+framework+mysql+php

Comment: Yes / No. Yes - you can use EF with MySQL - see [this link (requires MySQL Connector NET)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html). No - since EF is designed to be used in .NET applications, and as far as I know PHP isn't part of the .NET languages it's impossible. You'll need to google about PHP ORM solutions, there's plenty of them.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is a ORM for .NET, i't isn't a "port" to php or anything like that, and even in that case, i doubt it would be better than current ORM frameworks for PHP.

If you want to use an ORM with PHP, then you have a lot of options, you should read a bit about the alternatives and choose an ORM.

Personally, I use Doctrine framework http://www.doctrine-project.org/